# Oralce Join query performance

Tags: oracle, performance, join, oracle11gr2

I am looking for suggestions to see if there is any better way to perform this task. My problem is that there are 2 tables (`CUSTOMER` and `REF_DATA`). I am scanning `CUSTOMER` table for any matching patterns in `REF_DATA` table.

Table structures and sample data below.

```sql
-- Table structures
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUST_ID         NUMBER(10),
NAME            VARCHAR2(50),
EMAIL           VARCHAR2(50),
CONTACT_DETAILS VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE REF_DATA (
    CITY_NAME VARCHAR2(50)
);

-- Sample data - CUSTOMER
1   A   NA  +1 000 000 000
2   B   NA  abc SYDNEY xyz
3   C   NA  NEW YORK 1234
4   D   NA  DELHI, INDIA, 123456
5   E   NA  123456

-- Sample data - REF_DATA
NEW YORK
SYDNEY
DELHI
ADELAIDE
MELBOURNE
```

**Option #1**
Following is the join query. Though it is working, I think it is bad in terms of performance. If the `CUSTOMER` table has 1 million records, and `REF_DATA` has `20000` rows, the result set will be `1 mil x 20000` before the `WHERE` predicate is applied.

```sql
SELECT 
    contact_details
FROM 
    CUSTOMER cust,
    REF_DATA ref
WHERE
    REGEXP_INSTR(cust.contact_details, ref.city_name) > 0;
```

**Option #2**
With Option #2, as there is no need to join with any other table, It will be faster. However, it is limited by SQL Query length, and the number of patterns in REF_DATA table.

```sql
SELECT 
    contact_details
FROM 
    CUSTOMER cust
WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(contact_details, 'NEW YORK|SYDNEY|DELHI|ADELAIDE|MELBOURNE', 'i')
```

Is there any way to improve this ?

**Notes**

1. The column `CONTACT_DETAILS` does not have any Index defined.
2. The DB version is Oracle 11g R2.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much you can do here vis-a-vis indexing, because the city name might appear anywhere inside the contact details string.  This leaves your `WHERE` clause mostly non sargable.  I might suggest just using `INSTR` here, to avoid invoking a regex engine:

```
SELECT cust.contact_details
FROM CUSTOMER cust,
INNER JOIN REF_DATA ref
    ON INSTR(cust.contact_details, ref.city_name) > 0;
```

Note also that I have replaced your old school implicit join with an explicit inner join.  The above join is the preferred way of writing SQL these days (and has been, for nearly *thirty* years).

If you have a persistent need for this type of query, you might want to scrub the `CUSTOMER` table and create a new column which contains the extracted city name.  Then, you may index that column for better performance.